# New password different from 3 previous ones

Tags: php, mysql, security, change-password

So here's the deal: I'd like to force my clients to change their password every 3 months. That's easy. 
But I also want them to choose a different password which is different from the previous 3 password.

And the difficult thing is that I'm storing the 4 information (3 last passwords and date of the last password change) in the same row of the db.

So I'm setting `row-->old_passwords = date()::psw_1::psw_2::psw_3`
And checking `if($POST['password']== psw_1 || $POST['password']== psw_2 || $POST['password']== psw_3)`

But how do I store the new password as being psw_3, the old one becoming psw_2 and that one psw_1 - ultimately erasing the original psw_1 ?

Don't worry about the CWE-257 - passwords are hashed of course !

Comment: I'd think something like `update table set psw1 = psw2, psw2=psw3, psw3 = NEWPASSWORD where userid = $id` <-- parameterizing that query though..

Comment: `$POST` read up on superglobals http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php - syntax errors.

Comment: Dare I ask, How have you tried to do it before asking us for help?

Comment: You may dare, sorry that I didn't include that. I tried several ways but it didn't seem clean and after 20 iterations I didn't post the final result since it would have taken too long to explain what confusing things happened inside my brain.
I'm not asking people to to the work for me if that's what you're implying - but the best way to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should do an "UPDATE" query, updating the fields with the new passwords ? 
Something like this should work, but be sure to protect against mysql injection.

ALSO as said by  @Fred -ii- , `$POST['password']` is never gonna work, you should read about superglobals. `$_POST['password']` will give you a better chance of achieving what you are trying to do ;)

```
$mysql->query("UPDATE tableStoringPwd pwd SET pwd.psw1 = pwd.psw2  , pwd.psw2 = pwd.psw3, pwd.psw3 = '" . $newPwd . "' WHERE userId = ". $userId );
```

EDIT :

Comment: Assuming `$newPwd` is a string this will fail.

Comment: @chris85 assuming OP's using the right method for their superglobals ;-) which currently contains syntax errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- good point; will need to use sglobals correctly, hash the password using whatever mechanics they have, and parameterize this query.

Comment: @YannickHelmut Did it help you finally ?